# Swift CGPDFContextBeginPage and CFData

Tags: swift, core-foundation, cfdata, cfdictionary

I would like to create some PDF pages in Swift.

This is my code to create a PDF page

```
// Initialize context and other stuff
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, aDictionary);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, pdfPageRef)
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext)
```

I have a problem with the "aDictionary" variable. I would like to add the media box (which is CGRect type variable) value under the kCGPDFContextMediaBox key. The documentation tells me the following:
`The media box for the document or for a given page. This key is optional. If present, the value of this key must be a CFData object that contains a CGRect (stored by value, not by reference).`

In objective-c it is fairly easy to create a CFData from CGRect, but in Swift I am not sure how to create it. Here's my objective-c code:

```
CGRect mediaBox = CGRectZero;
CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const UInt8 *)&mediaBox, sizeof(mediaBox));
```

What should be the Swift variant?

Let's say somehow I've created a CFData object, the next "hard" step is to add this to a CFDictionary. Here's how I've tried:

```
let pageDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(nil, 0, nil, nil);
CFDictionarySetValue(pageDictionary, key: &kCGPDFContextMediaBox, value: data);
```

For these two line I receive the following error: `CFString is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T3'`

Do you have any clues how can I fix these two errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CFData` is “toll-free bridged” with `NSData`, and `CFDictionary`
with `NSDictionary`. So the following should work:

```
var mediaBox = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 612, height: 792)
let boxData = NSData(bytes: &mediaBox, length: sizeofValue(mediaBox))
let pageInfo = [ kCGPDFContextMediaBox as String : boxData ]
CGPDFContextBeginPage(context, pageInfo)
```

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
var mediaBox = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 612, height: 792)
let boxData = NSData(bytes: &mediaBox, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: mediaBox))
let pageInfo = [ kCGPDFContextMediaBox as String : boxData ]
context.beginPDFPage(pageInfo as NSDictionary)
```

Comment: Nice! The 'sizeofValue' saved my day. I've tried with just sizeof and it wasn't working.

Comment: @InfinitePossibilities: Yes, unlike C,  Swift uses differentiates between `sizeof( someType )` and `sizeofValue( someValue )`.